# Simultaneously looking at all elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with a single non-zero entry;

```
InfectionMatrix = zeros(10,10);
InfectionMatrix(5,5) = 1;
```

I want to look at this matrix find all the elements that have the value 1 then increase the value of surrounding elements by 0.125

```
for k = 1:1:8
    for j = 1:1:10
        for i = 1:1:10
            if InfectionMatrix(i,j) == 1
                InfectionMatrix(i-1,j) = InfectionMatrix(i-1,j)+      0.125; 
                InfectionMatrix(i-1,j+1) = InfectionMatrix(i-1,j+1)+  0.125; 
                InfectionMatrix(i-1,j-1) = InfectionMatrix(i-1,j-1)+  0.125; 
                InfectionMatrix(i,j+1) = InfectionMatrix(i,j+1)+      0.125; 
                InfectionMatrix(i,j-1) = InfectionMatrix(i,j-1)+      0.125; 
                InfectionMatrix(i+1,j+1) = InfectionMatrix(i+1,j+1) + 0.125; 
                InfectionMatrix(i+1,j-1) = InfectionMatrix(i+1,j-1) + 0.125;
                InfectionMatrix(i+1,j) = InfectionMatrix(i+1,j) +     0.125; 
            end
        end
    end  
end
```

This is what Ive done, and is what I mean by surrounding elements. I can only think of doing this using a loop but this way it looks through elements in order and doesn't give a 'wave' effect.

This is the kind of idea;

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0  --->

0 0 0 0 0

0 1 1 1 0

0 1 1 1 0 ---->

0 1 1 1 0

1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 ---->

1 1 1 1 1

The matrixes represent multiple iterations.

Where the maximum value can be one and the values all propagate from the centre increasing by 0.125 each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function im = spread(im)
    % Retrieve the matrix data...
    [im_rows,im_cols] = size(im);
    im_min = min(im(im>0));

    % Declare the indces...
    indices = [];

    for i = 1:im_rows
        for j = 1:im_cols
            % Skip the process if the current center is not equal to 1...
            if (im(i,j) ~= im_min)
                continue;
            end

            % Retrieve the neighboring column and row offsets...
            c = bsxfun(@plus,j,[-1  0  1 -1  1 -1  0  1]);
            r = bsxfun(@plus,i,[-1 -1 -1  0  0  1  1  1]);

            % Filter the invalid positions...
            idx = (c > 0) & (c <= im_cols) & (r > 0) & (r <= im_rows);

            % Transform the valid positions into linear indices and discard the invalid ones...
            idx = (((idx .* c) - 1) .* im_rows) + (idx .* r);
            idx = reshape(idx.',1,numel(idx));

            % Keep only the valid indices...
            idx = idx(idx > 0);
            idx = idx(im(idx) == 0);
            indices = [indices, idx];  
        end
    end

    % Increase the non-minimum (and non-zero) values...
    im(im >= im_min) = im(im >= im_min) + 0.125;

    % Take the elements with a value equal to 0 and increase them...
    im(indices) = im(indices) + 0.125;
end
```

Here is an example usage:

```
im = zeros(10,10);
im(5,5) = 0.125;

figure();
colormap(hot());

hold on;

for i = 1:8
    im = spread(im);

    subplot(4,2,i);
    imagesc(im);
    title(['Step ' num2str(i)]);
end

hold off;

caxis([0 max(max(im))]);
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for k = 1:1:8
    IMONES = (InfectionMatrix==1);
    KERNEL = 0.125*ones(3,3);
    KERNEL(2,2) = 0;
    InfectionMatrix += conv2(IMONES,KERNEL,'same');
end
```

Note that I have interpreted your "wave effect" as the succeeding elements influencing the preceding elements in the two innermost iterations. I have assumed that you don't want this to happen. The above solution has no "wave effect"

Comment: By the wave effect I meant that, in each iteration it would increase the surrounding elements by 0.125, and slowly propagate to the edges of the matrix. However this isnt really what im looking for.

Comment: You should probably explain, what you are looking for.